# Kendo MVC Grid ClientTemplate will lead to "Field not defined"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo MVC Grid which read action can be done successfully

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
  .Name("Name")
  .AutoBind(false)
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    ...
    columns.Bound(c => c.ItemCode).ClientTemplate("#= ItemCode #").Title("Item").Width(300);
  })
  .Pageable(page =>
  {
    page.Enabled(true);
  })
  .Scrollable(s => s.Height(400))
  .Sortable(s => s.Enabled(false))
  .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("MaterialFormEditor").Window(w => { w.Title(""); w.Width(700); }).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  .PageSize(20)
  .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.JobNo))
  .Read(read => read.Action(...)
  .ServerOperation(true)
  )
)
```

```js
  public class MyModel
    {
        public string ItemCode;
    }
```

(Above code is simplified, so the ClientTemplate content is simply the field value itself, yet the problem still can be reproduced)

Now the problem is, when I click the "Add new record" button, a javascript error comes out and no window is popped up.

The error said: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ItemCode is not defined`

Yet when I delete the `.ClientTemplate()`, everything goes right.

What is the cause of the error and how can I solve it?

Comment: We've had similar problems but with objects, so maybe try   `.Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.JobNo); model.Field(x=>x.ItemCode).Default("This is a test");)`

Comment: Turns out I do the same as you and fix the problem..I still don't understand why I have to do this because my object is flat, the fields are simple int / string...Also I have other similar grids that have no problem without setting model.Field() explicitly...

Comment: TBH we've only seen it on complex objects, so not sure why you'd have issues with primitive types.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, I know...

I had a similar issue and had to add backslashes to get it to work:

```
    columns.Bound(c => c.ItemCode).ClientTemplate("\\#= ItemCode \\#").Title("Item").Width(300);
```